# Is the below Javascript function being passed arguments by value or by reference? I'm not sure how to distinguish between the two

Tags: javascript, function, reference

I can't figure out what passing by reference and passing by value looks like (I know what they mean in theory). Can you tell me whether the below function is passing arguments by value ore reference? BTW this is my first post :)

```
var number_1 = 32;
var number_2 = 43;

function addition(num1,num2) {
    alert (num1*num2) ;
}

addition(number_1,number_2); /*is this passing by reference?*/
```

Comment: Technically everything in JS is by value, though for objects the value is a reference to the object. In your case, it's a simple copy of the number values.

Comment: everything in javascript is passed by value

Comment: Passing by reference is largely a concept in other languages, not Javascript. In Javascript, every variable is either a primitive type (numeric, boolean, string), or an object. Arrays are just objects that are built-in to the language and have special syntax.

Comment: can someone give me two simple examples of passing arguments by reference and by value side by side...I know that Javascript only allows passing by value but I can't understand how it works in my code. Doesn't passing an argument by reference mean passing a variable instead of a raw value?

Answer (score 5):

**Primitive types**

In javascript number, strings, boolean fall under the category of primitives.
And whenever such types are passed as arguments to a function, a separate copy is created inside the function scope which has no impact on the outer scope

for e.g

```
var number_1 = 32;
var number_2 = 43;
addition(32,43);
//number_1 is 32 here
//number_2 is 43 here

function addition(number_1,number_2) {
    number_1 += 1; // number_1 is 33
    number_2 += 1; // number_2 is 44
}
```

**Reference types**

Reference types are slightly different

Take the following example

```
var obj = new Object();
fn(obj);

function fn(object){
  object.property = "test";
  //obj.property is "test"
  object = new Object();
  object.property = "test 2";
  //obj.property is still "test"
  //obj.property should have changed to "test 2", 
  //if it had been passed by reference
}
```

if it had been passed by reference , `obj.property` should have got changed to "test 2" after the last statement inside fn, but it didnt.
so when passing reference values to functions, a separate copy of the pointer to the object is passed.

Comment: thanks, so basically what I did was pass by value then? I thought that passing by value meant passing a raw value like "thisisastring" and that passing a variable like number_1 meant passing by reference.

Comment: yes correct. you were passing by value and that is how it works

Answer (score -1):

In javascript every variable is passed by value not reference but there is an exception for objects. objects are references ([like it was answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language#answer-3638034)).

which means a number, a string, a boolean or a function don't change at all after you put'em as argument in a function. but an the propertues and the elements inside an object or an array change if they are changed inside a function.

Here is an example

---

### Simple variable

```
function nullify(a) 
{
   a = null;
}

var myVariable = 123;
nullify(myVariable); // myVariable still equals to 123
```

---

### Object

```
function changeProperty (obj)
{
   obj.key = null;
}

var myObject = new Object();
myObject.key = "value";
changeProperty(myObject); // the property key is null after calling the function
```

---

### Array

```
function changeArray (Arr)
{
   Arr[0] = null;
}

var myArray = [1,2,3];
changeArray(myArray); // now the value of myArray is [null,2,3]
```

Comment: Objects aren’t *passed* by reference; objects are references. Same as assignment.

Comment: @minitech I didn't say they are passed by reference

Comment: To quote from your first paragraph: *“In javascript every variable is passed by value not reference **except for objects**.”*

Comment: I said something and you understood something else!

Comment: Please clarify, then. If objects aren’t passed by value and aren’t passed by reference, how are they passed?

Comment: @minitech, check out the new update, I hope you will understand :) have a good day!

Comment: Okay, but that’s not an exception. Changing a property is completely different from assigning a new value to a variable. Primitives are immutable.

Comment: There's always an (Add Another Answer) button at the buttom of the page

Comment: No, your answer contains a link to the duplicate anyways.

Comment: If BOSS has the right answer then your comments are redundant

Comment: Not really. You could fix your answer or something, by the way.

Comment: No need to fix it, I think it's clear for most of the people who would read it

Comment: Yes, I believe it will give them a very clear picture that is wrong.

Comment: if you think that objects and arrays are assigned new values then why an object doesn't change in this case : `var x = {}; nullify(x);`

Comment: I don’t think that at all.

Comment: Here's what you've said **Changing a property is completely different from assigning a new value to a variable**

Comment: It is completely different from assigning a new value to a variable. What I said is exactly the opposite of that `var x = {}; nullify(x);` example.

Comment: Serially downvoting me is not creative at all. Also, imagine how you could have spent that time just fixing your answer!